# Как можно вытянуть длительность аудиофайла для андроид устройства?

Tags: android, android-ndk, c++

Как правильно можно взять метаданные из аудиотрека в андроид приложении (с++), если я использую для сборки Android Ndk.

Знаю, что в java для андроид приложений есть MediaMetadataRetriever, но в папке ндк я такого класса не нашел. Может, есть альтернатива? И как правильнее это сделать?

Comment: Вот [тут][1] посмотрите.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/327011/audio-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-mp3

Comment: Garfield, По вашей ссылке необходимо было расчитать длительность мп3, имея все нужные константы.  
В моем случае я могу узнать количество каналов и сэмплрэйт, но не знаю Duration. Т.е. на данный момент я хотел бы узнать, можно ли средствами андроид ндк вытянуть значение Duration.